# updating win32_printer management object takes so long

Tags: wmi, performance

I use following piece of code to change printers "port" property. Problem is it executes longer than a minute. 
Is there a way to speed it up?
Can i instantiate management object not with all properties of wmi object? And more importantly, how can i update only 1 property?
Maybe i should instantiate managementobject withouth searcher?

```
ManagementPath mPath = new ManagementPath();
mPath.Server = Server.TrimStart(new char[] {'\\'});
mPath.NamespacePath = "root\\cimv2";
ManagementScope mScope = new ManagementScope();
mScope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
mScope.Path = mPath;
SelectQuery sQ = new SelectQuery();
sQ.ClassName = "Win32_Printer";

//sQ.SelectedProperties.Add("PortName");
//sQ.SelectedProperties.Add("DeviceID");

sQ.Condition = string.Format("Name=\"{0}\"", Name);

ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mScope, sQ);
foreach (ManagementObject service in s.Get())
{
string oldname = service.Properties["PortName"].Value.ToString();
service.Properties["PortName"].Value  = PortName;
service.Put( );
this.Port = PortName;
return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ManagementPath mPath = new ManagementPath() ;
        mPath.NamespacePath = "root\\cimv2";
        mPath.Server = Server.TrimStart(new char[] { '\\' });
        mPath.RelativePath = "Win32_Printer.DeviceID=\"" + Name + "\"";
        ManagementObject Printer = new ManagementObject(mPath);
        string oldname = Printer.Properties["PortName"].Value.ToString();
        Printer.Properties["PortName"].Value = PortName;
        Printer.Put();
```

this one works faster, although I think it can be improved further.